# How to simulate a phone call income on iPhone Simulator?

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

I want to simulate a phone call in my iphone simulator. Or which method will be called if a phone calling me?

Answer (score 4):

There's an option in the menus to turn on the call status bar.

Hardware > Toggle In-Call Status Bar

Comment: That doesn't appear to do anything in the latest sim (Xcode 3.2.4)

Comment: That only toggles the status bar, it does not simulate a phone call.

Answer (score 4):

The incoming call should trigger applicationWillResignActive in the application delegate.