# Resizing an iOS view with Xamarin.iOS when call status bar is toggled

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

Is there a trick to detecting when the status bar changes height due to a phone call in Xamarin.iOS?

I'm trying to adapt the excellent instructions from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947226/iphone-how-to-resize-view-when-call-status-bar-is-toggled) to work in Xamarin, and the `ChangedStatusBarFrame` method is never called.

The following code doesn't do anything in a brand new Xamarin iPhone project:

```
public virtual void ChangedStatusBarFrame(UIApplication application, RectangleF oldStatusBarFrame)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Y U NO work!");
}
```

I tried the equivalent in a new native iPhone app and it worked perfectly:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didChangeStatusBarFrame:(CGRect)oldStatusBarFrame
{
    NSLog(@"Hey, the status bar changed size!");
}
```

I'm testing this on the iOS simulator by [toggling the status bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304813/how-to-simulate-a-phone-call-income-on-iphone-simulator).

I'm using Xamarin.iOS version 6.4.3.0 and XCode 4.6.3.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use override keyword:

```
public override void ChangedStatusBarFrame(UIApplication application, RectangleF oldStatusBarFrame)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Y U NO work!");
}
```

Comment: Oh, man, I feel like an idiot. I'll give that a shot, and I expect it'll work. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, that was it. I typed the `override` keyword when I started to define the method, but I ended up copying and pasting the entire signature from the Assembly Browser. Thanks for catching the problem!